# Why am I not learning anything from Minor Inscription Research?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a scribe (aka: "inscriptionator") in WoW who hasn't learned any new glyphs from minor research for the past few days.

Does this mean I've learned all the minor glyphs, or does performing the research just give a chance to learn and I'm unlucky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already maxed your Inscription skill? The Minor Inscription Research will only fail if you have already learned all available glyphs. However, some minor glyphs have a higher level (represented by the skill level at which you can gain skill by scribing them) which means you can't discover them until your inscription is at least as high as their skill level.

Currently there are **64** minor glyphs, so it might also help to count and verify if you have them all. Unfortunately, Wowhead's search function isn't properly differentiating between minor, major, and prime glpyhs, so I can't give you a better answer.

Comment: Oh, there are 63 minor?  I thought it was still 60... 6 per class.

Comment: At *least* 63, there used to be 6 per class, but patches have since added more. Like I said, I can't get WoWhead to filter the glyphs properly.

Comment: http://www.wowhead.com/items=16?filter=cr=132;crs=2;crv=0 should show all of the Minor glyphs properly filtered. According to that, there are 64 minor glyphs.

Comment: Ah, that's a better way to search for them too. I was searching via the inscription recipes themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Which Minor Inscriptions you can learn is also affected by your Inscription skill.

For example, you won't get Death Knight Minor Inscriptions until you have at least 275 skill, which, at 5 points per level, equates to level 55... the starting level for Death Knights.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers already posted: If there are any glyphs available to be discovered, research will *always* discover one of them. There's no luck involved.

Also, research will always produce some scrolls/vellums as a side effect even if you don't learn anything new.